# Reading and Writing to a file in java

Tags: java, io

So i'm currently working on a challenge program for fun. the challenge is to read an array from a file located in the working directory, reversing the array, and writing it back to an output file. Can someone point out my errors please? I looked for relevant previously asked questions and couldn't find any. I have gotten to the point of compiling and running my code but I cannot see any output at all. I know that the code does not reverse the array yet. I just want to see the content first and that is not working for me.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.File;

public class ReverseArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File in = new File("inputFile.txt");
    File out = new File("outputFile.txt"); 
    try{    
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out); 

        int[] array = new int[s.nextInt()];
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++){
            array[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        writer.print(array);
        writer.flush(); 
        writer.close();
       }catch(Exception e) { 

      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: what specific errors are you getting?

Comment: 1. I don't see where you're reversing anything. 2. Are you sure that the first number of the file indicates how many numbers are to be put in an array and reversed? It could be that the input files contains the numbers to write back in reverse, and nothing else.

Comment: The code compiles and I haven't started on reversing the array yet. My issue is that its not writing anything to the output file.

Comment: First thing to do: stop catching and ignoring exceptions. Second thing to do: use the debugger to step through the code to know  what it is doing. Or at the very least add traces to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the inputs and instead of writing the whole array write array element by element.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.File;

public class ReverseArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File in = new File("inputFile.txt");
    File out = new File("outputFile.txt"); 

    try{    
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out); 

        int[] array = new int[s.nextInt()];
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++){
                array[i] = s.nextInt();
                writer.print(array[i]);
        }
        writer.flush(); 
        writer.close();

       }
       catch(Exception e){

       }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first and foremost error is to have that part in your program:

```
catch(Exception e){

}
```

This can be written in English as "if some sort of error occurs and the program is unable to continue to process normally, please do not tell me about it and not give me the information you'd normally give when encountering that kind of error. Please keep from me any information that could help me analyze what's happening."

You should probably never have that kind of thing in a program.

If you really must have a try/catch, at the very least have it so:

```
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And in case of an error Java will provide you with useful information about where there was an error and the nature of it.

But better yet, get rid of the entire **try** mechanism altogether.

The compiler will complain that an IOException could occur, and you will resolve this like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

After you've made these corrections, you will be equipped with information about what's happening wrong in your program we will be able to further analyze your other problems.